# Cannot find module 'http2' when trying to start a parse server project for the first time

Tags: javascript, parse-server

So I'm starting my first project with parse and while following these direction in the docs

```
$ sh <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parse-community/parse-server/master/bootstrap.sh)
$ npm install -g mongodb-runner
$ mongodb-runner start
$ npm start
```

I get " Cannot find module 'http2' "
Has anyone come accross this and how can i get this project to start.

node -v => v8.3.0
mongo -v => v4.0.0

Comment: did you run the 'npm build' mentioned in 'package.json.scripts'

Comment: my package.json only has npm start as it's scripts.

Comment: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server  is a diff project then. i dont know where u are getting your project?

Comment: I got it from the the parse server website docs

Answer (score 2):

http2 requires at least v8.7.0.

So if if you don't have any NodeJS version manager yet, you can use https://github.com/tj/n

Assume you use `n`, run the command

`n lts`

to install the latest LTS (should be higher than 8.7.0 from this point on)

According to the doc, run

`parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test`

where APPLICATION_ID and MASTER_KEY can be any arbitrary strings. If that still fails then run

`npm i http2 -g`

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful to know what version of nodejs you're using. (you can get this by running **node -v**)

Try running: **npm install http2**

Older versions of node.js didn't support http2, it wasn't until very recently that native support for http2 was released.

Comment: my version number is 8.3 and i have once i do that i get another error " Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'. "
node_modules/apn/lib/client.js:18
  } = http2.constants;

Comment: "deprecated http2@3.3.7: Use the built-in module in node 9.0.0 or newer, instead"

Answer (score -1):

Can you open an issue on the repository please? This should work with your node version.